# Adding ColorPickerPreference Library when it's not a preference

Tags: java, android, color-picker, color-palette

I'm trying to add a ColorPicker to my app. I see a lot a of ColorPickers (the one frome the API'S Samples, [the one from Cyanogen](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_Settings/blob/527f17f73f76feee76f50d022c7b7629d288e312/src/com/android/settings/notificationlight/ColorPickerView.java), the [AmbilWarna library](https://code.google.com/p/android-color-picker/), the [HoloColorPicker](https://github.com/LarsWerkman/HoloColorPicker), and the [ColorPickerPreference](http://www.androidviews.net/2012/11/colorpickerpreference/)). I think that the best for my app is the last one, but I don't need to use it on a preference.

So, what I want is to use this library inside my project when I click a button, and then take the resulting code from the SharedPreferences(I think, I don't know it), and use that color as I want for my app.

I try to use only some of the classes (only [ColorPickerDialog](https://github.com/attenzione/android-ColorPickerPreference/blob/master/src/net/margaritov/preference/colorpicker/ColorPickerDialog.java), [ColorPickerView](https://github.com/attenzione/android-ColorPickerPreference/blob/master/src/net/margaritov/preference/colorpicker/ColorPickerView.java), [ColorPickerPanelView](https://github.com/attenzione/android-ColorPickerPreference/blob/master/src/net/margaritov/preference/colorpicker/ColorPickerPanelView.java) and [AlphaPatternDrawable](https://github.com/attenzione/android-ColorPickerPreference/blob/master/src/net/margaritov/preference/colorpicker/AlphaPatternDrawable.java)) and then I think that I have to do:

```
ColorPickerDialog dialog = new ColorPickerDialog(Main.this, Color.BLACK);
dialog.show();
```

And now I don't know how can I have the selected color.

Also I added to my project the [xml view](https://github.com/attenzione/android-ColorPickerPreference/blob/master/res/layout/dialog_color_picker.xml).

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To know what is the selected color you need to to:

```
color=dialog.getfinalColor();
```

So, I think that the problem was easy to solve it. But now the problem is find a listener to detect when the dialog is closed and then to save the variable "color".